# How to keep sound when holding the key?

Tags: java, android

Recently I create a Piano App and I used SoundPool class to create that Piano app. But Now was thinking to create a **Harmonium** App. And getting confused to apply the class.

I want to play sound till the key released. Not only once. The sound will stop when I press another key. But sound keeps playing till I hold that key.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use View.OnTouchListener . see here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener  you need to catch the event when a touch is released.

Also You May Try This button Listener Example

https://github.com/mRasey/OfficialProgram/blob/00b8dcc27220ba616c55134ca3a16f5ca7a06724/Talk2Me/app/src/main/java/com/codemine/talk2me/ButtonListener.java